Pandas, Data Validation with a second Dataframe
I have a pandas DataFrame with multiple columns like
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"FACHEXPERTISE":["AQ01","AQ03","AQ05"],"ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG":["ZF14","ZF45","ZF13"]})

and a second DataFrame which contains all possible combinations:
QUALI = pd.DataFrame({"FACHEXPERTISE":["AQ01","AQ01","AQ01"],"ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG":["ZF15","ZF30","ZF40"]})

Now, I want to check if all combinations in my df1 are valid and if not I want to delete the row.
The only way I could think of was something like this, but I always get an error that my str object does not have a .isin function:
df3.FACHEXPERTISE.apply(lambda x: x.isin(QUALI[QUALI.FACHEXPERTISE==x].ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG))

Could someone suggest another way?

Added new solution to my answer.

You can use inner join by both DataFrames and test if match values compare ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG columns, filter FACHEXPERTISE if match and last filter matched rows by Series.isin:
#codes in FACHEXPERTISE are unique
df3=pd.DataFrame({"FACHEXPERTISE":["AQ01","AQ03","AQ05"],
                  "ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG":["ZF15","ZF45","ZF13"]})

QUALI=pd.DataFrame({"FACHEXPERTISE":["AQ01","AQ01","AQ01"],
                    "ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG":["ZF15","ZF30","ZF40"]})


df = df3.merge(QUALI, on='FACHEXPERTISE')
s = df.loc[df['ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG_x'].eq(df['ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG_y']), 'FACHEXPERTISE']

out = df3[df3['FACHEXPERTISE'].isin(s)]
print (out)
  FACHEXPERTISE ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG
0          AQ01              ZF15

Another idea if need test each row separately is use mapping with sets with default empty set:
#codes in FACHEXPERTISE are duplicated
df3=pd.DataFrame({"FACHEXPERTISE":["AQ01","AQ03","AQ01"],
                   "ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG":["ZF15","ZF45","ZF13"]})

QUALI=pd.DataFrame({"FACHEXPERTISE":["AQ01","AQ01","AQ01"],
                    "ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG":["ZF15","ZF30","ZF40"]})

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda:set(), QUALI.groupby('FACHEXPERTISE')['ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG'].agg(set))
s = df3['FACHEXPERTISE'].map(d)

out = out = df3[[a in b for a, b in zip(df3['ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG'], s)]]
print (out)
  FACHEXPERTISE ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG
0          AQ01              ZF15

EDIT: Solution with Index.isin with DataFrame.set_index:
out = df3[df3.set_index(["FACHEXPERTISE","ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG"]).index
             .isin(QUALI.set_index(["FACHEXPERTISE","ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG"]).index)]
print (out)
      FACHEXPERTISE ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG
    0          AQ01              ZF15


You were on the right path.
import pandas as pd
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"FACHEXPERTISE":["AQ01","AQ03","AQ05","AQ06"],"ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG":["ZF14","ZF45","ZF13","ZF01"]})
QUALI = pd.DataFrame({"FACHEXPERTISE":["AQ01","AQ01","AQ01","AQ06"],"ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG":["ZF15","ZF30","ZF40","ZF01"]})

tmp = df3.isin(QUALI).astype(bool)
tmp.FACHEXPERTISE & tmp.ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG

tmp2 = df3.assign(IsIn=(tmp.FACHEXPERTISE & tmp.ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG))
tmp2[tmp2.IsIn==True]

EDIT: Old solution bellow (misunderstood the issue, thx for pointing it out Mike)
To display the information try this:
df3.FACHEXPERTISE.isin(QUALI.FACHEXPERTISE).astype(bool)

returns:
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: FACHEXPERTISE, dtype: bool

And to filter your dataframe:
tmp = df3.assign(IsIn=df3.FACHEXPERTISE.isin(QUALI.FACHEXPERTISE).astype(bool))
tmp[tmp.IsIn==True]

returns:
    FACHEXPERTISE   ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG   IsIn
0   AQ01            ZF14                True


i think this is not the right solution. This would just check if df3.FACHEXPERTISE is in my valdiation file. But what happens if there is a combination that is not allowed?

Thx for the notice, it should be all right now

the easiest and best solution i came up with is probably this:
df3["X"]=df3[df3.ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG.notna()][["FACHEXPERTISE","ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG"]].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(list(zip(QUALI.FACHEXPERTISE,QUALI.ZUSATZBEZEICHNUNG))).fillna(True)

just kinda ZIP both and do a .isin function
